# Como ativa componente de upload de javascript usando o UIKIT?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, file-upload

Essa pagina se trata de implementações de componente em Javascript usando o FrameWorks UiKit.

[Cliqui aqui para acessa a pagina de UiKit.](https://getuikit.com/docs/upload#javascript)

Estou tentando implementar o **Drop Area** como vocês podem ver na figura a baixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém estou enfrentando alguns problemas, e vou começar a descrever bem detalhadamente.

Eu fiz um teste no meu projeto com a implementação um pouco diferente da documentação, mas era para funcionar, mas não está funcionando.

O exemplo da documentação do UiKit é essa;

**HTML**

```
    <div class="test-upload uk-placeholder uk-text-center">
        <span uk-icon="icon: cloud-upload"></span>
        <span class="uk-text-middle">Attach binaries by dropping them here or</span>
        <div uk-form-custom>
            <input type="file" multiple>
            <span class="uk-link">selecting one</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<progress id="progressbar" class="uk-progress" value="0" max="100" hidden></progress>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

    (function ($) {

        var bar = $("#progressbar")[0];

        UIkit.upload('.test-upload', {

            url: '',
            multiple: true,

            beforeSend: function() { console.log('beforeSend', arguments); },
            beforeAll: function() { console.log('beforeAll', arguments); },
            load: function() { console.log('load', arguments); },
            error: function() { console.log('error', arguments); },
            complete: function() { console.log('complete', arguments); },

            loadStart: function (e) {
                console.log('loadStart', arguments);

                bar.removeAttribute('hidden');
                bar.max =  e.total;
                bar.value =  e.loaded;
            },

            progress: function (e) {
                console.log('progress', arguments);

                bar.max =  e.total;
                bar.value =  e.loaded;

            },

            loadEnd: function (e) {
                console.log('loadEnd', arguments);

                bar.max =  e.total;
                bar.value =  e.loaded;
            },

            completeAll: function () {
                console.log('completeAll', arguments);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    bar.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
                }, 1000);

                alert('Upload Completed');
            }
        });

    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

E esse é meu modelo;

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group  col-sm-12">
            <label class="control-label">Foto</label>

            <div id="upload-drop" class="bw-upload">
                <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i>
                <span>Arraste a foto aqui ou </span>
                <a class="bw-upload-form-file">selecione <input id="upload-select" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    var settings = {
            type: 'json',
            filelimit: 1,
            allow: '*.(jpg|jpeg|png)',
            action: '/arm/fotos'
    };

    UIkit.uploadSelect($('#upload-select'), settings);
    UIkit.uploadDrop($('#upload-drop'), settings);
});
```

Você percebe que meu modelo é bem mais simples, e é um modelo tirado de um projeto no GitHub encontrado na internet, mas é assim... era para funcionar.

A versão que estou usando do UiKit é da 2.27.4, eu achava que não estava conseguindo ativa por conta de não está importando certo os arquivos certos, mas não é esse o problema, estou deixando logo abaixo os aquivos que utilizei para a implementação.

[Upload.min.css](https://github.com/wladyband/UiKit/blob/master/css/components/upload.min.css) |
[UiKit.min.js](https://github.com/wladyband/UiKit/blob/master/js/uikit.min.js) |
[Upload.min.js](https://github.com/wladyband/UiKit/blob/master/js/components/upload.min.js)

Eu sei que não é problema de arquivos porque eu fiz um tester usando os arquivos estáticos como estou mostrando abaixo, peguei esse modelo de Links estáticos da documentação do UiKit;

**CSS**

```
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/css/uikit.css?nc=6094'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit.js?nc=6094'></script>
    <script src='https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.js?nc=6094'></script>
```

Com os links estáticos não tem margem de erro de arquivo!

Eu sei que meu problema está aqui;

```
$(function() {
        var settings = {
                type: 'json',
                filelimit: 1,
                allow: '*.(jpg|jpeg|png)',
                action: '/arm/fotos'
        };

        UIkit.uploadSelect($('#upload-select'), settings);
        UIkit.uploadDrop($('#upload-drop'), settings);
    });
```

O problema é saber porque não está ativando o JavaScript no componente abaixo;

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group  col-sm-12">
                    <label class="control-label">Foto</label>

                    <div id="upload-drop" class="bw-upload">
                        <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i>
                        <span>Arraste a foto aqui ou </span>
                        <a class="bw-upload-form-file">selecione <input id="upload-select" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Está faltando alguma coisa, mas não sei o que é.

Estou desesperado e aceitando sugestões.

===========================================================================

Sem saber o que estava havendo de errado resolvi analisar o meu projeto  minuciosamente, e tive a ideia de criar um projeto bem simples, esse projeto não tem entidades, nem regras de negócio, ele somente contém uma pagina HTML com importações de CSS e JavaScript.

E através de mini projeto conseguir identificar que o problema estava no código javascript.

dá uma olhada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela corresponde a primeira linha desse código JavaScript abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Cliqui aqui para ver o meu repositório do mini projeto](https://github.com/wladyband/upload/blob/master/upload/src/main/resources/templates/CadastroFoto.html)

Como você pode ver ele não conseguiu identificar a função no código JavaScript que é o **UIkit.uploadSelect** e o  **UIkit.uploadDrop**

O que acontece é que não consigo conectar esse arquivo javascript apesar se está conectando da forma correta.

```
<script th:src="@{/javascripts/upload.min.js}"></script>
```

Estou achando que o problema está na ferramenta IDE Spring Tools

Alguém poderia realizar um teste para mim por favor.

Comment: Apenas comentando, alternativa para upload drag-and-drop: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles

Comment: Pessoal eu somente preciso corrigir aquele pequeno código de JavaScript.